# To-Many relations Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I am new to the core data and am loving it so far, I just have a question on to-many relations and their inverses. I'm trying to create something where each unit can convert to many other units so each unit can point to many converters that point to just one other unit. The image below works perfectly, but I know that core data wants them to be inverse and lets me know. When I try to select this it eliminates the functionality I desire.

I have tried creating a new relationship on each entity to act like an inverse but it fails, I can get a set of null objects.
Basically I am trying to create a graph-like structure in core data.

Is it possible to get this functionality while making core data happy with supplying inverses?

[image: My Model]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to make inverses by adding a relationship to each entity. The Converter entity would get a `ConvertsFrom` to-one relationship which is inverse to the Converters relationship, and Unit would get a `ConvertedBy` to-many relationship (since it can be converted by many converters) which is inverse to the ConvertsTo relationship.